# Using Onsen UI with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, meteor-blaze, onsen-ui

In trying to use Onsen UI together with Meteor.js and Cordova, `onsen-css-components.css` and `onsenui.css` were copied to `client/css` and `onsenui.js` to `client/lib`. Onsen UI elements were used in a Meteor template in `app.html`.

However no CSS styles seem to be applied to these `ons-*` elements, as shown in screen cap below. What additional steps are required to apply Onsen UI styles to the template?

**app.html**

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">List With Header</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-header>Android Versions</ons-list-header>

    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">KitKat</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Jelly Bean</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Honycomb</ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-header>Mac OS X Versions</ons-list-header>

    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Mavericks</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Mountain Lion</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Lion</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">SnowLeopard</ons-list-item>

  </ons-list>

</ons-page>
```

**app.js**

```
ons.bootstrap();
ons.ready(function() {
    // Add another Onsen UI element
    var content = document.getElementById("#my-content");
    content.innerHTML="<ons-button>Another Button</ons-button>";
    ons.compile(content);
});
```

**Rendered Result**

[image]

**Javascript Console Errors**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined onsenui.js?6c0e6c9dd262aa6735d1d59f874924b40039dcde:3922
Uncaught ReferenceError: ons is not defined app.js?1177e75f0f0631724c9abb2b3ef5bb97373aca32:1
```

How can we use Onsen UI without the Angular dependency? Installed `mrt:angular-stack` on Meteor 0.9.2.1 and it seems that its not compatible with Meteor 0.9+

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the same thing. Looks like it's super tied to Angular: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/222

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, it's impossible to use OnsenUI tag without AngularJS. However, you can have OnsenUI style by using its CSS components which you can find here (http://components.onsenui.io/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add `urigo:angular` package to your meteor app. Check http://angular-meteor.com for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post as I also wanted to integrate OnsenUI for styling into Meteor.

I combined it with Blaze, by just getting the files the author above mentioned and copied where he described. Then added the corresponding class names from OnsenUI https://onsen.io/v2/api/css.html#button-category and it worked like a charm.

E.g., Blaze tutorial start page:

```
<head>
<title>testapp</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

{{> hello}}
{{> info}}

</body>

<template name="hello">
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
<p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="info">

<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-header">
        Learn Meteor!
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item__center"><a 
href="https://www.meteor.com/try" target="_blank">Do the Tutorial</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item__center"><a 
href="http://guide.meteor.com" target="_blank">Follow the Guide</a>
</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item__center"><a 
href="https://docs.meteor.com" target="_blank">Read the Docs</a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item__center"><a 
href="https://docs.meteor.com" target="_blank">Discussions</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>


</template>
```

Cheers